# Enable Python on IIS 3 on Windows Server 2003

Tags: python, web-services, iis

I've been developing python applications for a good long time now, never had a major issue, that is until I tried to enable it on Windows Server 2003. The oldest I had worked on before this is 2008, which is easy to get Python up and running: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276494

The Windows Server 2003 is scheduled to be upgraded in a few months, but until then I am working in  the stone age. I believe the IIS it is running is 3, but all I can see is Microsoft Management Console 3.0 version 5.2 R2 when trying to figure it out.

I've tried a few variants of the same method to get it working, but have had zero luck. I've got python installed, I've added it as an application (maybe), set up it to recognize .py files, but still nothing.

**If anyone can point me at a resource or provide some instructions that would be great.**

Here are some of my limitations:

- I cannot upgrade IIS
- I cannot install any add-ons to IIS
- I can't simply create a port and have it go to my Windows 8 PC.

Comment: IIS3 when the PC was still BC....

Comment: IIS 3? I guess built-in component of Windows Server 2003 is IIS 6.0. IIS 3 used to come with Windows NT Server 4.0 sp3. May be this link will give heads up. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276494

Comment: Well I think I am bountying this question.